# In what folder does Ngnix gets installed in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I'm trying to understand the Nginx folder structure.

In what folder (or folders) does Ngnix gets installed in Ubuntu Server?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe: `dpkg-query -L nginx`. Also, this is not really relevant for Stack Overflow, try Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian and it's derivatives like Ubuntu, you can use the command:

```
dpkg -L PACKAGE_NAME
```

to get a list of files installed by that package. For `nginx` it is:

```
dpkg -L nginx
```